# How to combine these method into one?

Tags: lightning-web-components, controller

```
public with sharing class bot{

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

public static List< Contact > fetchActive (Id accId) { 

return [SELECT Status_c, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Status_c='Active' AND AccountId=:accid ]; 

}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

public static List< Contact > fetchInactive( Id accid) { 

return [SELECT Status_c,FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Status_c='Inactive' AND AccountId=:accid 

  }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass status value in the method and try below approach :

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List< Contact > fetchInactive( Id accid, String status) {

    return [SELECT Status_c,FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Status_c=:status AND AccountId=:accid];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of combining these two methods.  It all depends on how you need implementation like return type and parameters to be passed to the method ..etc

As answered by @Rohit will be one way and other way is to return map<String, List> as return type as below.

```
public with sharing class bot {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, List<Contact>> fetchContactsByStatus(Id accId) {
        List<Contact> activeContacts = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact> inactiveContacts = new List<Contact>();
        
        for (Contact c : [SELECT Status_c, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accId]) {
            if (c.Status_c == 'Active') {
                activeContacts.add(c);
            } else if (c.Status_c == 'Inactive') {
                inactiveContacts.add(c);
            }
        }
        
        Map<String, List<Contact>> contactsByStatus = new Map<String, List<Contact>>();
        contactsByStatus.put('Active', activeContacts);
        contactsByStatus.put('Inactive', inactiveContacts);
        
        return contactsByStatus;
    }
}
```

You can get active and inactive contacts by getting the map values .